# PartialView must derive from WebViewPage error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am getting "must derive from WebViewPage" error when calling PartialView inside other folder instead Views folder.

**Error**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view at '~/Modules/HtmlContent/_HtmlContent.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.
PartialView adding
```

**Page.cshtml**

```
<div class="side">
    @Html.Action("Side")
</div>
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Side()
{
    return PartialView("~/Modules/HtmlContent/_HtmlContent.cshtml");
}
```

**File Hierarchy**

```
Modules
|
+-- HtmlContent
|             |
|             +-- _HtmlContent.cshtml
|
Views
    |
    +-- Home
    |      |
    |      +-- Index.cshtml
    |      |
    |      +-- Page.cshtml
    |
    +-- Shared
             |
             +-- Layout.cshtml
             |
             +-- _Partial.cshtml
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to put a web.config in the root of this custom folder. The same as `~/Views/web.config`. Inside this web.config you will find a section which indicates the type of the Razor pages:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Notice how the `pageBaseType` is set to `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`.

Alternatively you could add the following to the top of your Razor views:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
```

Comment: Hi @Darin Dimitrov, i tried you proposed solution. Actually I have created Area. I have adding a web.config file in my Area View Folder but still no luck.  Alternate solution is working but you know it is hard to add for each view.